# Grails dynamically update template view without ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, templates, grails, gsp

I'm trying to inform the user the progress of a task with a GSP template (this is displaying in an overlay)

The user submits their data and the controller calls a service to complete the task. During this process I have another service that works out the percentage complete calculation and returns the value to a function (below). Depending on the size of the task this calculation service can be called many times by the first service.

```
    def progress(progressData) {

    def statusToView = progressData

    [statusToView:statusToView]
    }
```

I don't think I can use Ajax remoteFunction call because I won't be passing the property 'progressData' from the GSP template to the controller - this would give an error of missing property.

All I'm wanting to do is display the percentage (statusToView) value to the user upon it updating and when the process has finished the function that started off the task redirects to a page informing the user the job is done.

template code is simply the variable value:

```
     ${statusToView}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

1. You can start a timer and make an AJAX call to the server to get the latest update.
2. You can create a [WebSocket](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/). WebSocket is an bi-directional API where browser and server can send messages at any time. Callbacks on both ends will be notified when a message arrives.

The WebSocket API would allow your service to push updates to the browser as they happen.

The next problem is the template. You can't use a normal template in this case. My suggestion is to write a template with a `<div id="updates">Starting...</div>`. In your JavaScript callback, you can then locate this element by ID and replace the content with the latest message from the server.

Comment: I don't think I can make an Ajax call though because I'm not passing the property to the function where it's expecting 'progressData'. Looks like WebSocket API is the way to go although I was hoping for a quick fix! Thanks Aaron.

Comment: You need to put the progress data as an attribute into the session on the server. The AJAX controller will then take it from there. You need a way for the service to update the session attribute. The easiest way to do this is to define a "monitor" interface which takes update messages and an implementation which has access to the current user's HTTP session. On the client, you just need to make the AJAX call and put the result in the DOM.

Comment: thanks again Aaron, we're on Grails 2.4.3 so can't use websockets for now. I'll try and figure out this Ajax call, I thought I was getting quite good at Grails but this work has set me back a bit. thanks